# How to synchronously check if app is still authorized with javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I tried it with:

```
var auth_response = FB.getAuthResponse();
```

But that always gives back the authResponse with access token even if the app had been deauthorized. I expected a different result.

I have also tried subscribing into the authResponseChange.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', checkFbAuthorization);

function checkFbAuthorization(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        fb_authorized = true;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        fb_authorized = false;
    }
```

But checkFbAuthorization did not get called when I deauthorized the app from the facebook account settings page.

I also tried with just using fb.login but it did not open a popup if the app was deauthorized.

A possible explanation is that i should wait longer, i tried it several times to wait longer but also without result.

Comment: Did you find a solution for ur problem? thanks

Comment: I'm also looking for some synchronous solution so the click event can open new window, did you find something?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this demopage:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Helper-Component-Community/222933037808340?sk=app_412923142052609

there is an button for checking if you are connected! Remember that you have to re-visit the app after removing the auth from your application list because the auth is saved for each visit via JS!

Edit: this one button just tests if you are connected. You can chain the requests and events to get an auth-workflow for your app :)

Comment: Is it assync? Cant check the source code as its not free it seems.

Comment: You can add a success- and error-callback to the function call isConnected(). The success or error-callback will be performed AFTER retrieving the information if the user is connected or not

Comment: Yea so it uses assync right? Its the same as calling getLoginStatus, I want to call it synchronously so I can stay within the click event. Are you affiliated with them? Just wondering, thanks for your help in either way

Comment: I guess the problem is that the facebook functions saves the responses in something like sessions and you will not get a new valid response until you reload the application.